# Show InfoWindow onMouseOver in Google Maps v3 without a Marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map which has polygons defining various locations.

I am trying to trigger an infowindow when the pointer mouses over the polygon, and then remove it when the mouse leaves. i have center coordinates for the polygons, and there is no marker.

All of the infowindow examples I found are based on having a marker point.

How can I acheive this without a marker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach the infoWindow creation to the polygon `mouseover` event. Then have the window close when the user mouses out. Something like this:

```
google.maps.event.AddListener("mouseover", polygon, function() {
    infoWindow.setPosition(latLng)
    infoWindow.open(map)

})
google.maps.event.AddListener("mouseout", polygon, function() {
    infoWindow.close()
})
```